# Connotation of the word “Mischling” for Germans

Tags: connotation

Back story: A few months ago, my school hosted some German exchange students. I don’t know any German, as I chose French classes, but anyhow an American female friend of mine in my math class was one of the students in the exchange program, so she came to class with two exchange students. The German students (two girls) sat close to me. I made them feel welcome as it was their first day and they seemed a bit nervous to be in the spotlight. So I chatted with them in English and introduced myself, and joked with them that I wish I could speak German, but I only knew Spanish, English and some French … basically I ended up flirting a little with one of them.

I’m a Hispanic/Latino (Colombian-American) olive-skinned male. At some point when they were talking German to each other, I heard one girl distinctly say *Mischling* in their fast convo.

I have a pretty good ear, especially for foreign languages, so I’m sure I heard right and I think they were referring to me since as I learned from movies and stuff that *Mischling* means a person of mixed race (which I can pass for).

So that left me wondering do Germans use this word lot? And does it carry negative connotations?

Comment: Please.consider removing unrelated information such as the first paragraph except for its last phrase. It's faster and easier to grasp your question then.

Comment: General advice: if you don't speak the language, don't try to interpret anything you think you get. You'll get a more accurate picture from reading their behaviour. If she's flirting with you, she's probably not talking in a bad way about you. Yes, they may have been guessing what your genetic makeup is (or trying to figure out how to ask you about it) but they might as well have been talking about a dog they saw earlier.

Comment: I would be wary assuming you heard the correct word, especially if you could not use grammar cues. If they said for example "Mischung", this would have been much more neutral.

Comment: I think a large part of the first paragraph is important for the context of the question. This also makes it important to judge the usage of the word in question and thus makes it directly related and useful information

Comment: @Raphael For what it's worth, only one of the German girls was sort of flirty/talking to me. The other one, the one who actually said the word in question, was not so much into it. It might be that she was jealous? But I have no idea.

Comment: @Vogel612 I agree, and I am appalled at how much this question was changed by the 2nd edit. Not only is it now harder to understand some of the older comments and answers, the editor also changed expressions of completely subjective and individual perceptions. It belongs only to the OP to choose between "I'm sure", "I think" or "I believe". No 3rd person should change such wording without the OP's consent.

Comment: FWIW the second edit was by an anonymous user. I have no idea why this went through the edit queue but I used my privilege to roll back the edit. Any further discussion about this should be moved to [meta]. I can also be found in [chat] in case there are objections. In case of more vandalizing edits I will flag this post for moderator attention. Additionally to already given points the edit partly invalidated already given answers!

Comment: @Matthias when you see such things happen, don't hesitate to flag for moderator attention. If you think an edit was invalid you have the right  (and imo duty) to object.

Comment: @Vogel612 Thank you. I haven't been here for long, and I saw this edit being approved, so I wasn't quite sure about how to act and a bit afraid of starting an edit war.

Comment: @Matthias I've been here for almost 2 years now. I didn't witness any edit wars yet and I have full confidence in our mods to act if something were to happen. Whenever you have questions like that: [chat] and [meta] are your best chances to get an answer:)

Comment: thanks for the responses guys. I wish I could provide an update to the backstory but I never saw or spoke to the German girl again. They must have sent her to sit in with a different class. And I am too embarrassed bring it up with my American friend, who is of German ancestry and might think I'm trying to say her friends were racists or something.

Comment: Also I wish I could read the comments written in German... lol oh well, might take me a while to decipher even with google translate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To me, the word sounds extremely sketchy. It is certainly not a form of intentional overt racism, or a slur. It is not amongst the standard repertoire of insults against ethnicities, minorities etc., and it's not the kind of word you'd not say in front of your grandmother. But I have never heard anybody use that term, and I would be very surprised if I heard it. I would expect mostly racist people to use it.

(That and how it is applied to dogs and isn't insulting there I find little comfort in. Neither does it comfort me that they went for "Mischling" with their stereotyping.)

The reason for my discomfort would be that "Mischling" implies some *normative standard of purity regarding human races*. How extremely problematic every aspect of this idea is I probably need not elaborate on. Moreso as in Germany, classifying people into races is both uncommon even in colloquial discourse, and extremely politically incorrect. (German racism typically follows slightly different patterns.)
So while the word itself may not carry racist *connotations*, the factual situation it presupposes is a racist worldview.
By that I do not mean you should take that girl to be racist. She probably didn't put any thought into it. It's just one word, uttered in a possibly confusing and stressful situation.

Comment: … by a teenager. (Addition to the last sentence.)

Comment: @jona: So, which german word would you recommend for "people with ancestors of different skin color"?

Comment: @hellcode: I doubt that such a word exists at all. Even *Mischling* is not restricted to different skin colours. I would not even know of an English word for this. Also, there is no big need for such a word, as you are hardly ever talking about such people in general. Thus you can usually use a more specific term.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I agree, on both counts.

Comment: Germans, as a rule, are increasingly hesitant to talk about race (in humans) at all, even flat-out denying the concept as such. (An official form asking you to specify your own race would be unthinkable, e.g.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I have read that in the USA the term "mixed-race person" shall be a fairly neutral description (e.g. for Obama).

Comment: Es ist allerdings eine kühne These dass in Deutschland Menschen nicht anhand ihrer Hautfarbe klassifiziert würden. Wenn man Deutschland nur vermittelt über Fernsehen und Zeitungen kennt, vieleicht - im gemeinen Volk ist von Bimbo bis Fidji, von Mischling bis Mulatte alles vertreten. Man sollte sich da keinen Illusionen hingeben und nicht andere noch ermutigen wegzusehen. Probleme verschwinden nicht dadurch, dass man sie ignoriert.

Comment: @hellcode: Den deutschen Rassisten gilt Obama, gemäß der One-Drop-Doktrin, als Schwarzer, nicht als Mischling.

Comment: @hellcode: *mixed-race person* includes much more than “people with ancestors of different skin color”.

Comment: @user unknown: "Es ist allerdings eine kühne These dass in Deutschland Menschen nicht anhand ihrer Hautfarbe klassifiziert würden" <- Sicher. Ich glaube auch nicht, irgend jemand hier würde solch eine These vertreten. Nur verstehe ich nicht, wie das hier relevant sein soll?

Comment: I wonder whom I owe the two downvotes to. Racists who disagree with my political correctness, or anti-racists who think I'm not going far enough?..

Comment: @user unknown: Was willst du mit deinem Kommentar zu Obama sagen und was hat das noch mit der ursprünglichen Frage, die du im übrigen sinnverändernd gekürzt hast, zu tun?

Comment: @hellcode: Dass Obama in dt. Qualitätsmedien unzählige Male als erster schwarzer Präsident bezeichnet wurde, obwohl er nicht mehr schwarz als weiß ist. Das ist nicht überraschend, sondern als one-drop-doktrin bekannt: "Wer auch nur einen Tropfen fremden Blutes in sich trägt gehört nicht zuu uns", ist also nicht weiß sondern schwarz. Btw.: Ich habe die Frage nicht gekürzt wie man in der Historie leicht überprüfen kann; ich habe das Wort Mischling groß geschrieben, wiewohl ich meine Zweifel habe, da wir ja Anglizismen auch in dt. Grammatik schreiben, also Substantive groß (Händie, Baby, Paper).

Comment: @jona: `Moreso as in Germany, classifying people into races is both uncommon even in colloquial discourse, and extremely politically incorrect.` Wenn nicht über die Hautfarbe, worüber sonst? Zu sagen, die Frau sei kein Rassist weil sie die Stereotype, die die Mehrheit der Rassisten um sie herum teilt, noch nie erfolgreich hinterfragt hat, ist m.E. eine Entschuldigung des Rassismus - entschuldigt qua Ignoranz. Dem liegt die Vorstellung zu Grunde der Rassist müsse ein leicht identifizierbares Monster sein, mit Springerstiefeln und Baseballschläger mindestens. Aber doch keine Studentin.

Comment: "Wenn nicht über die Hautfarbe, worüber sonst?" <- Dieser Satz liest sich auf Deutsch sehr merkwürdig. Nicht sprachlich, sondern historisch. Wie ich bereits gesagt habe, "German racism typically follows slightly different patterns". Es gibt sicherlich irgendwo auf StackExchange auch ein Subforum, wo die Frage danach *on topic* wäre.

Comment: @user unknown: Entschuldige bitte, dass ich dachte, du hättest die Frage gekürzt. Das mit dem anonymen User hatte ich nicht geblickt. Tut mir leid.

Comment: @jona: Was liest sich daran merkwürdig? Wieso folgt deutscher Rassismus Mustern und welchen? Andere Muster als früher, andere Muster als gestern? Welche neutralisierende Auswirkung hat das auf die Hautfarbe? Du redest um den Brei herum und sagst damit letztlich gar nichts. Leere Behauptungen.

Comment: @hellcode: Kein Problem.

Answer (score 6):

The Duden, the most influential German dictionary, warns in its entry on [Mischling](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mischling):

> "Usage of the word *Mischling* to denote persons is increasingly
>   regarded as discriminating since it is reducing people to their
>   biological origin."

So there is a large and growing number of people that would see this word carrying a negative connotation, but also another group that wouldn't. (I'd question their mindset, though.)

The Duden also says about the [suffix '-ling'](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/das-suffix-ling):

> "In conjunction with adjectives it [i.e. the nouns constructed this
>   way] often denotes people that are characterized by a certain quality.
>   ... These constructions frequently have a strong deprecative
>   character."

'-ling' is capable of turning "schön" (beautiful) into "Schönling" (pansy / pretty boy). This doesn't happen for all words with '-ling', e.g. "Lehrling" (apprentice) or "Zwilling" (twin) are perfectly neutral, but in general these constructions aren't something nice to say about people. I think it depends on your *sprachgefühl* whether you see "Mischling" affected by this.

As for the frequency of use I haven't profound statistics, but 9 of my top ten Google hits for the word concern dogs (and the tenth is the Wikipedia article on Mischling). That seconds somehow my experience that dog races is the context where this word survives in contemporary German.

Comment: That first quote from Duden sounds like PC-bullshit to me. I don't think I've ever heard "Mischling" applied to humans, that is in particular not in a derogatory way.

Comment: @Raphael: Note that the Duden is just describing here and its description is certainly correct. Anyway, this statement (»*Mischling* is regarded as discriminating, since …«) could be applied to any other word with the same or similar meaning and is in a certain way correct, since there are very few situations, where you would need such a word for non-discriminating purposes (even more so than words describing the skin color, which serve a purpose for describing what somebody looks like).

Comment: @Raphael well, for the reason you have given (seldomly used for humans) this is no PC bullshit. It is - independend of the language - increasingly uncommon to treat humans based on their ethnics. This is one reason you hear "Mischling" mostly for dogs. And the fact you have a word used for animals also means you are carefully to apply it to humans (same is true for "Stallion", "Full-Blood", etc). So I would say it is at least a sign for insensitiveness (caused by having no exposure to other ethnics).

Comment: @Raphael: It isn't. I heard the generation of my grandmother talking about mixed races with darker skin in that way. She dind't even mean it in any bad way, it was just the words she grew up with.

Comment: Well, the generation of our grand-parents crew up with either minimal exposure to race, with open hatred against them or seggregation beeing the norm. I would not say that using the tone from this time is a good thing to carry over.

Comment: Während der Duden das politisch korrekte sagen will ist die Weise, in der er es tut, blamabel, wiederholt er doch die affige Pharse von der Reduktion auf etwas. Als Dudenredaktion sollte man sich die Reflektion leisten können, dass jedes Substantiv, das eigene Eigenschaft beschreibt, als solche Reduktion aufgefasst werden könnte, ob Deutscher, Teenager, Mann, Schreiner, Herthafan, Fußgänger oder was immer. Es kann also nicht die Reduktion auf eine Eigenschaft sein, die hier problematisch ist. Vielleicht arbeiten da aber auch nur noch Praktikanten und Hochstapler.

Comment: @userunknown: Das Problem ist doch, dass gewisse Leute diverse Worte, die Eigenschaften beschreiben, (z. B. *Schwarzer, Behinderter, Asiate, Ausländer, Migrant*) eben so auffassen, selbst wenn sie z. B. in einer Vermisstenbeschreibung genutzt werden. Das nimmt ohne Zweifel teils übertriebene Maße an (z. B. im Begriff »Menschen mit Behinderung«), ist aber nun mal Realität – und der Duden hat hier nicht mehr getan, als dies korrekt zu beobachten.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Ich weiß nicht was Du mir sagen willst, bzw. ob Du erfasst hast, was ich sagte. Wie fassen gewisse Leute (ich nehme an Rassisten?) diverse Worte (Mischling) auf? Als neutrale Darstellungen eines Sachverhaltes, auf den die Person reduziert wird? Oder packen sie nicht viel mehr noch ein ganzes Bündel mitgemeinter Bedeutungen in das Wort, von faul über verschlagen, von dumm über schmutzig, was das Repertoire an Vorurteilen gerade hergibt? Statt zu beobachten und zu benennen labert der Duden rum.

Comment: +1 as this answer is pretty much a better sourced take on mine.

Comment: @userunknown: Nochmal anders: »die affige Phrase von der Reduktion auf irgendwas« (oder das Konzept) nutzt der Duden nicht, sondern er gibt sie nur wieder. Und dieses Konzept wird nun mal insbesondere von Leuten angewandt, die es mit der politischen Korrektheit übertreiben, und zum Beispiel *Menschen mit Behinderung* statt *Behinderte* hören wollen, obwohl das m. E. gar nichts verbessert. Im Gegensatz zu *Behinderter* ist die Situation mit *Mischling* allerdings komplizierter, da es praktisch keine nicht-rassistischen Anlässe für dieses Wort gibt – das liegt aber an seiner Bedeutung.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Wäre das nur die Wiedergabe eine fremden Aussage, dann wäre es wohl als Zitat gekennzeichnet. Es ist zweifellos eine Phrase, die der Duden selbst nutzt und der dabei distanziert und überlegen wirken will. Die Diskussion hier ist m.E. nicht rassistisch aber kommt nicht ohne das Wort Mischling aus. Auch der Dudeneintrag ist nicht rassistisch. Auch die Frage von cunninglinguist ist nicht rassistisch.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich zitiere (fett von mir): »Die Verwendung des Wortes *Mischling* als Personenbezeichnung **gilt** wegen der damit verbundenen Reduktion auf die biologische Herkunft **zunehmend** als diskriminierend.« Das ist für mich ganz klar eine Beobachtung. Und wenn es keine besseren Beispiele für eine nicht-rassistische Verwendung des Begriffs gibt als die Beschäftigung mit dem Begriff selbst (und vielleicht die Beschreibung der Meinung von Rassisten), sehe ich mich in meine Aussage, dass es »praktisch keine nicht-rassistischen Anlässe für dieses Wort gibt«, bestätigt.

Comment: An "user unknown" und @Wrzlprmft: ich sehe Eure Diskussion hier mit gemischten Gefühlen. Einerseits erscheint sie mir off-topic, weil sie in Form von Kommentaren zu meiner Antwort geführt wird, die aber längst nicht mehr meine Antwort kommentieren. Andererseits finde ich sie interessant und sähe sie auch gern noch weitergeführt. Was meint ihr, wäre "Wie kann man besser als der Duden ausdrücken, warum 'Mischling' als Personenbezeichnung zunehmend als diskriminierend empfunden wird?" eine gute Frage für German Language SE?

Comment: @Matthias: Ich halte die Frage für völlig abwegig; für geschichtsfälschend. Mischling wurde schon immer diskriminierend benutzt und natürlich auch so empfunden. Es war nur der Normalfall ein Rassist zu sein und deshalb war die rassistische Empfindung nicht von Schuldgefühlen und Scham begleitet. Es wird übersehen dass in einer rassistischen Gesellschaft Rassismus kein Problem ist, sondern normal. Diskriminierung wird als normal empfunden. Heute wirde Diskriminierung zunehmend stigmatisiert, aber nicht flächendeckend, nicht von jedem und nicht immer und überall.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the word itself is neutral. It is just a word for people with ancestors of different skin color, but as often it depends in which context it is used.

I would have expected that they use "Latino" instead. Latino has more the touch of being hot and sexy, because some latino singers are very popular here. But maybe they thought that you would understand that. So I cannot say what they exactly meant with it.

The word has further meanings. For example we use "Mischling" often for dogs to say that it is a crossbreed.

To answer your questions: the word is used quite often (but more in context with dogs, just because there are so many...) and normally (and I think especially in your case) it carries no negative connotation. Some people may feel that it is pejorative (maybe because the word is also used for dogs, maybe because it's reducing the group of people to their skin colour), but we don't have another word in german to describe shortly these people unless you know the exact origin.

Comment: Also das Kind eines Nordiren mit einer Griechin ist kein Mischling, oder eines Chinesen mit einer Vietnamesin oder eines Vaters aus Benin mit einer Mutter aus Mocambique? Nur beim Kreuzen von Hautfarben, von denen aber nur 4 unterschieden werden? Und das soll neutral sein?

Comment: Der Witz ist, dass es die vier klischeehaften Hautfarben gar nicht so gibt. Weder sind Asiaten herausragend gelbhäutig, noch sind Indianer rothäutig. Und zwischen »schwarz« und »weiß« (die natürlich auch nicht genau ihrem beschreibenden Wort entsprechen) gibt es beliebig viele Abstufungen.

Comment: Die ursprüngliche Fragestellung hatte nichts mit dem hier mittlerweile hineininterpretierten Rassismus zu tun. Es ging um eine Situation mit zwei Schülerinnen im Schüleraustausch, mit denen der Fragesteller geflirtet hat und meint, dabei den Begriff "Mischling" aufgeschnappt zu haben. Meint Ihr wirklich, dem Fragenden mit Euren Kommentaren weiterzuhelfen?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard the word "Mischling" being used to denote people for a really long time, and if then only rarely and by somewhat older people. I would even go so far as to say that the common teenager (ok, I mostly overhear conversations in public transport to get their "style" of talking, but nevertheless) would feel the word being rather wrong when used for people. Most likely *because* when used for people -- while not being distinctly negative -- it somehow feels like word out of times where it was meant to have a negative connotation.

More likely when talking about people of mixed descent, Germans use terms fitting to the prevailing phenotype. Depending on their social background, these terms are meant in a derogatory way, or not.

Where I hear this word really often is when talking about dogs. Every dog that isn't purebred is called "Mischling" in one or another way. A good way to figure out how people use words in German is in my experience to do a search for this word on the German google. Unless it is some kind of word explanation site (wikipedia, dictionary etc.) I think you have to scroll very far in the results to see it being used in any other context than dogs.

Unless you understood anything else from their conversation that would indicate this direction, I would deem it highly unlikely that she was talking in that way about any human. I would probably bet good money on that she saw a dog earlier that day or something like that.

Comment: @Carlster: I am not sure if I parse your sentence correctly, but the question was based on the (imho) false presumtion that the word was used to refer to a human. Also the question included if this word was used "a lot"; so this answer focuses on that and the most common usage that I know around me.

Answer (score 1):

The only context in which I have heard this word is for pets, and more specifically, dogs. Of course people are proud when they can say that their dog is a purebred but they'll also happily enumerate the races that make their dog a *Mischling*. Sometimes I even felt that it's used a little to compensate (for their dog not being a purebred) - this is not to say that *Mischling* has a negative connotation.

*Promenadenmischung* may have a slightly negative connotation (used when you don't know the races of your dog).

This is all about common language, not scientific terms.

(I am German)

Answer (score -1):

I personally think "Mischling" does not have a negative connotation.

Basically, it depends mostly on **how** you say it. I wasn't there and can't judge the intonation but If they were really talking about you (and not a dog or a mule), I wouldn't worry. German girls often like the "southern type" as we call it here.

"Bastard", which is sometimes used in colloquial language, is way more negative (Bastard is most used for dogs and other animals. for Humans it actually means "child born outside marriage").

A german word that describes your origin best would be "Mestize" (Child of a white person and of an indigenous person, mostly from middle- and south-america) but no one knows this word. The word "Latino" would have too easy for you to understand...

Comment: I don't get it, what does "bastard" have to do with all of this?

Comment: @Carlster when you refer to for example a dog when you say "Bastard" it means the same as "Mischling". This use is not correct when you refer to humans because of the formerly named definition. But people still use the incorrect term "bastard" to describe people who are in fact "Mischlinge". I just wanted to point out that there would have been worse words to describe you if they would have wanted to give a negative connotation.

Comment: I never heard people use it "colloquially" in that way. Maybe racists. Additionally I think "Bastard" was originally a positive term.

Comment: @Carlster was originally and is is a horse of different color. The etymolgy of a word surprisingly often has no say in the usage and meaning..

Comment: @Vogel612 [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bastard) and [The Grimm Brothers](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GB01059) disagree, where does your information come from?